# Sequelize: SQL Server 2014: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: sequelize.js, sql-server-2014

Trying to insert timestamps using sequlize in SQL Server 2014, but the dates always inserted as '۲۰۲۱-۰۷-۱۳',N'۰۱:۵۷:۱۱.۳۲۳' or something similar.

The query run:

```
sql: `INSERT INTO [product] ([uid],[modelNumber],[createdAt],[updatedAt]) OUTPUT INSERTED.[uid],INSERTED.[modelNumber],INSERTED.[createdAt],INSERTED.[updatedAt] VALUES (N'10057314',N'test',N'۲۰۲۱-۰۷-۱۳ ۰۱:۵۷:۱۱.۳۲۳',N'۲۰۲۱-۰۷-۱۳ ۰۱:۵۷:۱۱.۳۲۳');`,
```

Comment: Well where do those values come from?

Comment: Automatic time stamps. I think the date is inserted in arabic for some reason.